# Random internal subnet when on VPN

Tags: vpn, home-networking, isp, subnet, traceroute

Forgive me if this may seem unclear - I'm just trying to understand the workings behind this. While troubleshooting an unrelated issue on my home network, I was tracert'ing an address and naturally notice the first hop at was my gateway 10.0.0.1. When pinging the same address through my VPN, my first hop was a random IP everytime 10.x.x.x. I ran an IP scan on this subnet and there was always 2 IP's in this range.

Example:

The destination is anything external. For instance with no vpn, I trace 8.8.8.8, the first hop on trace will be 10.0.0.1 my router. When I connect to my vpn and trace it will be 10.41.3.1 or 10.32.1.2 or a random combination of the like 10.x.x.x. There is no problem I am receiving, just curious as to how my Comcast modem/router is working

No issue is caused by this, I'm just genuinely interested in what is happening.

Comment: The destination is anything external. For instance with no vpn, I trace 8.8.8.8, the first hop on trace will be 10.0.0.1 my router. When I connect to my vpn and trace it will be 10.41.3.1 or 10.32.1.2 or a random combination of the like 10.x.x.x. There is no problem I am receiving, just curious as to how my Comcast modem/router is working.

Comment: What VPN software stress you using?

Comment: Private Internet Access is the service I'm using and only one client connecting through.